# Is there any tools for generating bluetooth noise, in general or directed to a particular device?

Tags: bluetooth

Would anyone know of any tools to generate a noisy bluetooth environment?

I may need to create a noisy environment without doing this manually, or with lots of devices with different bluetooth profile support.

Better yet, it would be great if i could direct some noise to a device.

If the tools needs linux, I'm good :)

Thanks lots

Answer (score 0):

2.4Ghz

A Wi-Fi hub or Microwave oven on full blast should do the trick.

Seriously though, what are you trying to test? BT is quite resistant to interference as the ISM band is very noisy (even without Wi-fi and microwave ovens).